# Plotting an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

I need to draw an ellipsoid with an equation on this form:
$$
(Kx+y+z)x + (Ky+x+z)y + (Kz+x+y)z = 1
$$
where K is a constant.

Here is an example of wolfram drawing it for $K=8$: http://goo.gl/Ds5WWe

The program i'm using accepts ellipsoid in this form:
$$
{x^2 \over a^2}+{y^2 \over b^2}+{z^2 \over c^2}=1
$$

How does K relate to a, b and c?

I have tried using high school algebra and come up with this:

$$
K x^2+K y^2+K z^2+2 x y+2 x z+2 y z = 1
$$

Comment: Isn't possible write this ellipsoid in the canonical form that you want. The axes aren't the coordinate axes.

Comment: Does the program you're using allow a rotation matrix (to rotate the axes of the ellipsoid). If not, you're out of luck, as the first comment said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments your ellipsoid is rotated in such a way that its coordinate axes are no longer given by the standard basis. So it can **not** be written in your form.

But it is possible to describe exactly in which way the coordinate axes are tilted.

I assume $K>2$. Then there exists $c>0$ such that $K=c^2+\frac{1}{c^2}$. Then

$$\left(cx+\frac{1}{c}y\right)^2+\left(cy+\frac{1}{c}z\right)^2+\left(cz+\frac{1}{c}x\right)^2=Kx^2+Ky^2+Kz^2+2xy+2yz+2xz$$

That is, your ellipsoid is the preimage of the standard sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ under the invertible linear transformation

$$T\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=\pmatrix{cx+c^{-1}y\\cy+c^{-1}z\\cz+c^{-1}x}$$

which can be written in matrix form as

$$T=\pmatrix{c & c^{-1} & 0\\0 & c & c^{-1}\\ c^{-1} & 0 & c}$$

This matrix (or rather, its inverse) describes the way in which you have to stretch and rotate the standard sphere to obtain your ellipsoid.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $K>1$. If you only want to know $a, b, c$, you can diagonalize the matrix

$$A=\pmatrix{K & 1 & 1\\1 & K & 1\\ 1 & 1 & K}$$

the eigenvalues are $K-1, K-1$ and $K+2$. So $a, b, c$ would be

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{K-1}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{K-1}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{K+2}}$$